# VBA Run-time error 13 - type mismatch- price time series calc not working on array

Tags: arrays, vba, time-series

I suspect my question has a very simple answer, and yet I cannot find an answer that I understand in searching all over the site.

- `Ticker1` = an array of stock prices (1 to 2542)
- `PctChg1` = an array which I hope will ultimately hold the results of
  `(Price_last / Price_prev) - 1`
- `i` = counter

Code:

```
For i = 2 To UBound(Ticker1)
    PctChg1(i, 1) = Ticker1(i, 1) / Ticker1(i - 1, 1) - 1
Next i
```

Something about the `Ticker1(i - 1, 1)` part it does not like - I have fooled around with ranges as well and cannot make sense of this. I don't know why it thinks I am dividing by a number that isn't there - if i am starting at point `2` of the array, why wouldn't I be able to reference point `1` ?

Comment: why `i = 2` not `i = LBound(Ticker1)`? Are you sure both arrays are of the same size/dimmensions?

Comment: I used i=2 and not Lbound(Ticker1) because I need a minimum of 2 days to calculate a % change.

Answer (score 0):

```
For i = 2 To UBound(Ticker1)
    If Val(Ticker1(i - 1, 1)) <> 0 Then PctChg1(i, 1) = Ticker1(i, 1) / Ticker1(i - 1, 1) - 1
Next i
```

This works, but I still have not established why `i-1` generates errors when I start the calculation on data point `i=2`.

Comment: is the value of i-1 ever 0?  If it is, it will cause an error.  Since the modifications you made above specifically check that i-1 <>0 before doing the calculation solves the issue, it leads me to believe that in some instances the first value of your array is 0 and it's throwing the error.

Comment: agreed, just can't figure out why. there is a price in Ticker1(i,1).